# Subtracting dates with Deedle

Tags: f#, deedle

I want to get the difference between two dates. Ideally to add this back into the frame as a new column.  Have tried the code below but get "Overloaded subtraction operator"

```
let df = Frame.ReadCsv("someDateColumns.csv", hasHeaders=true, separators="|")
let s1:Series<int,DateTime> = df.GetColumn<DateTime>("StartDate")
let s2:Series<int,DateTime> = df.GetColumn<DateTime>("EndDate")
    
    
let s3  = s2 - s1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree this would be a nice addition to Deedle. If you were thinking of contributing, it should be relatively easy to add - it would be a matter of adding another overload to the [list of supported overloads in the Series module](https://github.com/fslaborg/Deedle/blob/master/src/Deedle/Series.fs#L1008), which currently has vector binary operations for various numerical types and strings.

Without changing Deedle, the easiest option is to use the `Series.zipInto` operation, which aligns two series (no-op if they came from the same data frame) and applies an operation to matching elements:

```
#r "nuget: Deedle"
open Deedle
open System

let df = 
  Frame.ofRecords 
    [ {| Start=DateTime(2000,1,1); End=DateTime(2000,1,10) |}
      {| Start=DateTime(2000,12,1); End=DateTime(2001,1,1) |}]

let s1 = df.GetColumn<DateTime>("Start")
let s2 = df.GetColumn<DateTime>("End")
    
let s3  = Series.zipInto (-) s2 s1
```